# SQL : Error converting data type nvarchar to float as part of a Union

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, union

I'm trying to create a master list of Mpxns from 2 tables and the join this master list to another table

Mpxns can be 8-13 digits long (all numeric)

In the offcoms table they are stored as a float
In the DCC table they are stored as NavChar (20)
In the health table they are stored as NavChar (50)

I'm combining the offcoms and DCC tale into a temp table and then trying to link the mpxns in that table to the health table but get the navchar to float error on line 21  [select t1.pod]

I've tried converting the offcoms to navchar in the union and also tried converting the t1.pod to navchar as part of the final select, but can't figure out the solution

Original query

```
SELECT * into ##temp1 

from
(select [esme_sap_mpxn]
FROM [DOMCustomers].[Bart].[OffComs14_1]
  
  union
  
select [gsme_sap_mpxn]
FROM [DOMCustomers].[Bart].[OffComs14_1]
  
 union
  
select  MPxN
from  [DOMCustomers].[dbo].[DCC_Remote_Commissioning_Main]

Where DATE_BOCT_SENT > = '2020-11-05') as tmp


select t1.pod 
,s2h.Premise
,s2h.[Meter Health Status]

from ##temp1 as t1
left join [DOMCustomers].[Bart].MeterHealth as s2h on t1.pod=s2h.Mpxn
 
drop table ##temp1
```

Trying to convert float into navchar during the union

```
SELECT * into ##temp1 

from
(select Case when isnumeric ([esme_sap_mpxn]) =1 then cast ([Esme_sap_mpxn] as nvarchar)else 0 end as POD
FROM [DOMCustomers].[Bart].[OffComs14_1]
  
  union
  
select Case when isnumeric ([gsme_sap_mpxn]) =1 then cast ([Gsme_sap_mpxn] as nvarchar)else 0 end as POD
FROM [DOMCustomers].[Bart].[OffComs14_1]
  
 union
  
select  MPxN
from  [DOMCustomers].[dbo].[DCC_Remote_Commissioning_Main]

Where DATE_BOCT_SENT > = '2020-11-05') as tmp


select t1.pod 
,s2h.Premise
,s2h.[Meter Health Status]

from ##temp1 as t1
left join [DOMCustomers].[Bart].MeterHealth as s2h on t1.pod=s2h.Mpxn
 
drop table ##temp1
```

I can't use 'TRY_CONVERT' as its is not a recognized built-in function name.  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v10.0.6000.29

Comment: FYI `ISNUMERIC` is a poor function at best, use `TRY_COVNERT`. Also, not declaring your length, scale or precision for data types is a *very* bad habit you need to get out of.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to try_convert function. Unless a value can't converting, you may saw that with try_convert function. In this way, choose not convertible value and filter it. If it is necessary, you can make different solution for that.

TRY_CONVERT Example:

```
select [esme_sap_mpxn], TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [esme_sap_mpxn]) FROM [DOMCustomers].[Bart].[OffComs14_1]
```

Comment: 'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name. :(  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v10.0.6000.29